# WebView2 control is not downloading the image files or any JS file mentioned in the page which we try to view in control

Tags: wpf, .net-core

For my single page application, I would like to view the web pages of the angular application in the EdgeView2 control from the wpf application.

As you know, the single page application has js files in the `index.html` page. When I provide the website link in the Edgeview2 control of my windows app, it is not showing the complete web page.

I ran Fiddler to trace the request and response. There I saw that the JavaScript files are giving notFound http status. The same page is viewed from the browser properly where all the js files and images are downloaded and the page is functioning correctly.

Could anyone please help me?

Comment: Did you mean they *are* returning a "not found" status? Or are they returning anything other than `200`?

Comment: Just a guess... Do you run locally? Probably JavaScript is blocked on local machine.
If you are running from a website (www.example.com/myApp/index.html). Then you will need to provide more details about your code.

Comment: @RichardDeeming the page is giving a 200 status, but for the js files and image which is supposed to be used it has notfound status for for it

Comment: @Patfreeze not locally, this is hosted in a different machine.

Comment: any idea of how to make the whole page work properly with the script files ?

Comment: @Sats That's odd. Have you compared the request for the script files sent from the WebView2 with the request sent from the browser to see if there are any differences? Maybe the site is doing something odd like user-agent sniffing.

Comment: @Sats I also faced same issue.. to fix the issue use page hierarchy like Main Folder will contains Index.html and all images.. If referring from some other path except same folder, it will not work.